# Returning entries from a data set that contain a specific string in Python

Tags: python, string, string-matching, data-extraction

I have a data set called `df` with the information of the name of the Drugs that has been administered. The column `"drug_name"` consists of all the various drug names. I would like to extract entries that only contain a specific name of the drugs.

I have tried the .str.contain method

`df_adr= df[df["drug_name"].str.contains("epinephrine")==True]`

This works but the problem is it returns entries that has the drug name `"Norepinephrine"` too because the word contains my key word `"epinephrine"`. How do I get extract the entries that is an exact string match and not contain the string?

Comment: Did you try something like `df[ str(df["drug_name"]) == "epinephrine" ]` ?

Comment: I tried and it returns me an error "False"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a regular expression with word boundaries `'\b'`.

```
df.loc[df["drug_name"].str.contains(r"\bepinephrine\b", case=False)]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. But how would I change the code if I want to extract entries that contain multiple specific strings?